# Buttons without class when build iOS

Tags: ios, button, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having some difficult to generate a build for iOS, when the build finishes and the app opens (on device or emulator) all the `<button>` tags appear without classes or ionic attributes.

It occurs in my MacBook Pro. In other computers it works.

I've tried the following:

- Upgrade/Downgrade NodeJS/NPM
- Ionic state restore
- Reinstalled xCode
- Reinstalled Cordova
- Run npm install a lot of times
- Removed platform and add it again

But without success.

I'm using Ionic 2 Beta.

Anyone have some idea what is happening?

Comment: Have you tried deleting contents of your derived data folder?

Comment: Hi @emreoktem I've tried everything. Now, I'll try to reinstall the Mac OS X.